# How to paginate subarray in MongoDb using nodeJS

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, pagination

I'm building chat application with MongoDB **(mongoose for object modeling)**

I have **room** collection and i store messages in array of a room document.

demo:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e91bcd6cd1630213d95f810"),
    "users" : [ 
        ObjectId("5e57d64d92cc878760086980"), 
        ObjectId("5e79f882def34451678278c7")
    ],
    "messages" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5e95bdeb43756876056c46fc"),
            "text" : "World",
            "user" : ObjectId("5e79f882def34451678278c7"),
            "createdAt" : ISODate("2020-04-14T13:43:07.953Z")
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5e95bc5c43756876056c46fb"),
            "text" : "Hello",
            "user" : ObjectId("5e79f882def34451678278c7"),
            "createdAt" : ISODate("2020-04-14T13:36:28.284Z")
        } 
    ]
}
```

Now i want to retrieve messages 10 by 10 and i can't use **$slice** method.

How can i retrieve messages like this:

```sql
SELECT * FROM messages WHERE createdAt > "2020-04-14T13:36:28.284Z" LIMIT 0, 10
```

Comment: Why don't want to use `$slice`?

Comment: @Ashh application is real time. there could be new messages or something else. i can't rely on indexes to slice. so, client sends last message to server, and server must retrieve next 10 messages by its created date.

Comment: use $filter aggregation

Comment: @MoazzamArif thank you, I am new for MongoDb. $filter helped me.

Answer (score 0):

aggregation **$filter** helped me. Thanks to @MoazzamArif.

```js
Chat.aggregate([

    {
        $match: {
            _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(roomId)
        }
    },

    {
        $project: {
            messages: {
                $filter: {
                    input: "$messages",
                    as: "message",
                    cond: {
                        $gt: ['$$message.createdAt', new Date('2020-04-14T13:36:28.284Z')]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

])
```